# Related to Insertion of records in Spatial Db sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, spatial

HI When i am trying to insert a record in one of the tables in my db using the following query its not working

```
insert into T_HTK_ZONES(ZONE_NAME,ZONE_GEOLOCATION) 
    values('TMH',GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((86.17768049240112 22.799901048907312, 86.17795944213867 22.802432999994917, 86.18175745010376 22.802531903379716, 86.18210077285767 22.799584551714144, 86.17946147918701 22.79849658700764, 86.17768049240112 22.799901048907312))', 4326))
```

This is not working

but this is working

```
insert into T_HTK_ZONES(ZONE_NAME,ZONE_GEOLOCATION)    
    values('TMH',GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-122.358 47.653 , -122.348 47.649, -122.348 47.658, -122.358 47.658, -122.358 47.653))', 4326))
```

Here is the error.

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined
>   routine or aggregate "geography": System.ArgumentException: 24200: The
>   specified input does not represent a valid geography instance.
>   System.ArgumentException: at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.ConstructGeographyFro‌​mUserInput(GeoData
>   g, Int32 srid) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(Ope‌​nGisType
>   type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.STGeomFromText(SqlCha‌​rs
>   geometryTaggedText, Int32 srid)

Can anyone pls explain

Comment: Are you getting an error trying to insert these values?

Comment: Yes for first query I am getting error second query is working fine i want to know why first is not working

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
System.ArgumentException: 24200: The specified input does not represent a valid geography instance.
System.ArgumentException: 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.ConstructGeographyFromUserInput(GeoData g, Int32 srid)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.STGeomFromText(SqlChars geometryTaggedText, Int32 srid)

Comment: What is the datatype of `ZONE_GEOLOCATION`? I did a query with your values into a variable of `georgaphy` and it worked fine in Query Analyzer.

Comment: It's of system.geography type

Comment: Have you tried that insert statement in SSMS?

Comment: I tried inserting it in sql server using query function availaible in visual studio not tried with SSMS

Comment: See if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271349/the-specified-input-does-not-represent-a-valid-geography-instance-exception-wh

Comment: That works Reversing the order of points works Thanks a lot for the help