# Error while inserting records in Geospatial Database in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, geospatial

I am using following query to insert records in GeoSpatial Db in SQL server 2008:

```
insert into T_HTK_ZONES(ZONE_NAME,ZONE_GEOLOCATION) 
 values ('TMH',GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(
   'POLYGON(
    (86.17768049240112 22.799901048907312,
     86.17795944213867 22.802432999994917,
     86.18175745010376 22.802531903379716,
     86.18210077285767 22.799584551714144, 
     86.17946147918701 22.79849658700764, 
     86.17768049240112 22.799901048907312)
   )', 4326))
```

I am getting following error  can anyone please help

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography":
>   System.ArgumentException: 24200: The specified input does not represent a valid geography instance.
>   System.ArgumentException:
>      at   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.ConstructGeographyFromUserInput(GeoData g, Int32 srid)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.STGeomFromText(SqlChars geometryTaggedText, Int32 srid)
>   .
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Have you read the second error message? Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271349/the-specified-input-does-not-represent-a-valid-geography-instance-exception-wh can help you.

Comment: So will changing order of points help ??

Comment: At least it is worth to try it out.